# Encoding PHP - How to encode php using Zend Studio?

Tags: php, zend-studio

I am new and unfamiliar with Zend studio and I was tasked to encode my php code for a project.

I had a hard time following this [tutorial](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/content/tutorials.htm) and can't seem to get anywhere. 
Can anyone help me get on the right track?

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you have a license for [zend guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/zend-guard)?

Comment: Yes, I have....

Comment: Then read [this](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Guard/content/obfuscating_code.htm) and follow the instructions on the bottom of the page.

Comment: You give the link is for zend guard, not for zend studio...http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/downloads#Windows